# es un proyecto de una calculadora, y ocupo poder hacer las operaciones basicas pero ingresando datos desde el teclado

Tags: vb.net

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de una calculadora, con las operaciones básicas

Funciona ingresando datos al presionar botones con números y signos, pero al momento de hacer operaciones con teclado no me funciona.

Aquí esta todo el código que tengo:

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Dim dato As Double
    Dim dato2 As Double
    Dim resultado As Double
    Dim operacion As Double
    Dim memoria As Integer

    Private Sub Btn0_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btn0.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = "0" Then
            TextBox1.Clear()
        End If
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "0"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Btn1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btn1.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = "0" Then
            TextBox1.Clear()
        End If
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "1"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Btn2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btn2.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = "0" Then
            TextBox1.Clear()
        End If
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "2"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Btn3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btn3.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = "0" Then
            TextBox1.Clear()
        End If
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "3"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Btn4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btn4.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = "0" Then
            TextBox1.Clear()
        End If
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "4"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Btn5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btn5.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = "0" Then
            TextBox1.Clear()
        End If
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "5"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Btn6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btn6.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = "0" Then
            TextBox1.Clear()
        End If
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "6"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Btn7_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btn7.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = "0" Then
            TextBox1.Clear()
        End If
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "7"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Btn8_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btn8.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = "0" Then
            TextBox1.Clear()
        End If
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "8"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Btn9_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btn9.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = "0" Then
            TextBox1.Clear()
        End If
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "9"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Btnsuma_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btnsuma.Click
        operacion = 1
        dato = dato + Val(TextBox1.Text)
        TextBox1.Clear()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Btnresta_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btnresta.Click
        'TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + "-"
        operacion = 2
        dato = dato + Val(TextBox1.Text)
        TextBox1.Clear()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Btnmultiplica_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btnmultiplica.Click
        operacion = 3
        dato = Val(TextBox1.Text)
        TextBox1.Clear()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Btndivide_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btndivide.Click
        operacion = 4
        dato = Val(TextBox1.Text)
        TextBox1.Clear()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Btnexpo_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btnexpo.Click
        'operacion = 5
        dato = Val(TextBox1.Text)
        resultado = dato ^ 2
        TextBox1.Text = resultado
    End Sub

    Private Sub Btnraiz_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btnraiz.Click
        dato = Val(TextBox1.Text)
        If dato < 0 Then
            MsgBox("opcion invalida")
        Else
            resultado = dato ^ (1 / 2)
            TextBox1.Text = resultado
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Btnigual_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btnigual.Click
        dato2 = Val(TextBox1.Text)
        If operacion = 1 Then
            resultado = dato + dato2
            TextBox1.Text = resultado
            resultado = Val(TextBox1.Text)
        ElseIf operacion = 2 Then
            resultado = dato - dato2
            TextBox1.Text = resultado
            resultado = Val(TextBox1.Text)
        ElseIf operacion = 3 Then
            resultado = dato * dato2
            TextBox1.Text = resultado
            resultado = Val(TextBox1.Text)
        ElseIf operacion = 4 Then
            If dato2 = 0 Then
                TextBox1.Text = "ERROR"
                'MsgBox("NO SE PUEDE DIVIDIR ENTRE 0")
            Else
                resultado = dato / dato2
                TextBox1.Text = resultado
                resultado = Val(TextBox1.Text)
            End If
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Btnborrar_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btnborrar.Click
        If TextBox1.Text.Trim() <> "" Then
            TextBox1.Text =TextBox1.Text.Remove(TextBox1.Text.Length - 1, 1)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Btnlimpiar_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btnlimpiar.Click
        TextBox1.Clear()
        TextBox1.Text = "0"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Btnmemoria_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btnmemoria.Click
        memoria = resultado
        TextBox1.Text = memoria
    End Sub

    Private Sub Btnpunto_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btnpunto.Click
        If InStr(TextBox1.Text, ".", CompareMethod.Text) = 0 Then
            TextBox1.Text &= "."
        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub Buttonnegativo_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Buttonnegativo.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = "0" Then
            TextBox1.Clear()
        End If
        If InStr(TextBox1.Text, "-", CompareMethod.Text) = 0 Then
            TextBox1.Text = "-"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs)


    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
        If TextBox1.Text = "0" Then
            TextBox1.Clear()
        End If
        If Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Or e.KeyChar = vbBack Or e.KeyChar = "." Or e.KeyChar = "/" Then
            e.Handled = False
        Else
            e.Handled = True

        End If
        If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 48 Then
            Btn0.PerformClick()
        ElseIf Asc(e.KeyChar) = 49 Then
            Btn1.PerformClick()
        ElseIf Asc(e.KeyChar) = 50 Then
            Btn2.PerformClick()
        ElseIf Asc(e.KeyChar) = 51 Then
            Btn3.PerformClick()
        ElseIf Asc(e.KeyChar) = 52 Then
            Btn4.PerformClick()
        ElseIf Asc(e.KeyChar) = 53 Then
            Btn5.PerformClick()
        ElseIf Asc(e.KeyChar) = 54 Then
            Btn6.PerformClick()
        ElseIf Asc(e.KeyChar) = 55 Then
            Btn7.PerformClick()
        ElseIf Asc(e.KeyChar) = 56 Then
            Btn8.PerformClick()
        ElseIf Asc(e.KeyChar) = 57 Then
            Btn9.PerformClick()
        ElseIf Asc(e.KeyChar) = 47 Then
            Btndivide.PerformClick()
        ElseIf Asc(e.KeyChar) = 43 Then
            Btnsuma.PerformClick()
        ElseIf Asc(e.KeyChar) = 45 Then
            Btnresta.PerformClick()
        ElseIf Asc(e.KeyChar) = 42 Then
            Btnmultiplica.PerformClick()
        ElseIf Asc(e.KeyChar) = 46 Then
            Btnpunto.PerformClick()
        ElseIf Asc(e.KeyChar) = 61 Then
            Btnigual.PerformClick()
        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        TextBox1.Focus()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Hola @JorgeLuque mira así como esta esta pregunta pude llegar a cerrarse, te pido por favor que la edites y agregues un poco mas de detalle de lo  que quieres lograr o el inconveniente que tengas así todos podemos ayudarte mejor. El link para editar la pregunta se encuentra arriba de los comentarios y justo abajo de donde termina lo que has escrito.  Y me olvidaba  bienvenido a Soes

Comment: Actualmente no se entiende cual es tu problema y no te podemos ayudar muchi, si editas tu pregunta y agregas mas detalles recibiras mejores respuestas

Comment: es un proyecto de una calculadora, pero el codigo que tengo y el que he pulicado es para poder hacer las operaciones basicas pero ingresando datos desde el teclado no presionando con el mouse, pero no me funciona al momento de presionar en teclado lo unico que hace es tomarlos como un caracter y no como un operando

Comment: @JorgeLuque veo que estás agregando la descripción en el título, y lo deberías agregar en el "cuerpo" de la pregunta, el título debería reflejar una idea general de lo que quieres preguntar, se entiende? no tengas miedo a responder y consultar para eso estamos todos. abrazos.

Comment: @JorgeLuque podrías publicar el código de los eventos de los botones?

Comment: @Alan lo puse en un comentario talves asi se entiende y en la pregunta esta solamente el codigo que tengo para poder validar eso

Comment: @Mariano de todos los botones? o solamente de los operandos

Comment: Bien ahora va quedando mejor, en la pregunta no solo puede ir código, debería ir todo lo relevante a tu problema, así todos lo pueden ver y se entiende la cuestión a resolver, solo te faltaría un mejor título y seguro queda una linda pregunta.

Comment: alli esta todo el codigo que tengo programado

Comment: @Jorge asegurate de tener la propiedad `KeyPreview` en `true`

Comment: del textbox o de la forma?

Comment: @mariano me puedes ayudar con ese codigo que dices?

Comment: @mariano gracias Bro eso era no me habia fijado, soy nuevo en programacion!!

Comment: ahora me surgio otro problema!!

Comment: @Jorge deberías aceptar la respuesta haciendo click en la marca a la izquierda de la misma, y para el nuevo problema publicar una nueva pregunta

Answer (score 0):

La propiedad `KeyPreview` permite que el formulario dispare los eventos asociados a teclas antes de que pasen al control que tiene el foco.

> #### [Form.KeyPreview (Propiedad)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview(v=vs.110).aspx)
>
> Cuando esta propiedad se establece en **true**, el formulario recibirá
>   todos los eventos [KeyPress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx), [KeyDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx), y [KeyUp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup(v=vs.110).aspx). Después
>   de que los controladores de eventos del formulario han terminado de
>   procesar la pulsación de tecla, se le asigna al control con foco.

<sup>*Modifiqué un poco el texto original porque era una traducción horrible.</sup>

Ya sea por código:

```vb
Me.KeyPreview = True
```

o en el diseño del Form

[image: Ventana de propiedades del Form]

Al configurar esta propiedad, se procesan todas las teclas desde el formulario, independientemente del control que posea el foco. Además, probablemente se quiera que el resto de los controles no reciban la tecla (evitando, por ejemplo, imprimirla duplicada). Para eso, se detiene el procesamiento del evento con:

```vb
e.Handled = True
```

---

Nota: Si se quiere interceptar las teclas a un nivel más bajo (y más eficiente), véase [Form.ProcessCmdKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.form.processcmdkey(v=vs.110).aspx). En este caso se omitió para simplificar la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias Mariano

Comment: @JorgeLuque Me alegro que te haya servido. Si esta respuesta ayudó a solucionar el problema de tu pregunta, por favor considera [aceptarla](/help/accepted-answer) haciendo click en el **✔️**, que está a la izquierda, bajo las flechas de votación (no se te descuenta nada por eso -todo lo contrario, se gana reputación).